# What status code represents : POST failed to add an employee because their corresponding id doesn't exist?

Tags: status

400 error codes confuse me and I'm not sure which this corresponds to! What status code represents POST failed to add an employee because their corresponding id doesn't exist?

Comment: Please provide more information. 400 is a generic code used by many APIs when a problem occurs. Start by listing what your code is, what you are trying to do and what your expected result is. Make sure to include as much detail as you can about the specs of the API you are trying to connect to.

Comment: HTTP doesn't have a specific code for "failed to add an employee because their corresponding id doesn't exist".  HTTP codes tend to be a bit more generic than that.  Are you asking what code you should use as the API designer?  That may be fairly opinion-based.  For example, if the `id` is part of the route and it's not found then that sounds like a 404 regardless of the operation.  Or if the route is correct but data supplied is not then that could be a 400.